# I'd like to know if I can push 40 volts at 3 amps through an IRLZ44N MOSFET?

Tags: current, transformer, nmos, overheat, spike

I already have the [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567217c32725), it states it can handle 50 volts at 50 amps but I'm worried about spikes since I'm using it to switch the primary side of the transformer at 70 Hz and it will be a square wave signal, so my concern is won't it over heat quickly since I'm near the 50 Vds point? And won't the 3 amps just make things worse?

Comment: A square wave means on and off. When the MOSFET is on there won't be 50V across it anymore. When it is off there won't be 3A flowing anymore. Dissipated power is the product of voltage across the device and current trough the device.

Comment: yeah, you can't push "voltage" through something. We might talk about current, but if current flows, then that voltage won't be 40 V. So, I think you need to get your basics straight. Maybe start by doing what we basically always need: Draw the schematic that involves your MOSFET, and **clearly** mark between which two points you are seeing 40 V, and through which cut 3 A flow. Then we can deliberate about things on a common basis! (Voting to close – lacking clarity without a schematic)

Comment: If you turn the MOSFET on hard, the resistance will be low (~0.025 ohms). The static power is fine, i^2R = 3^2 * 0.025 = 0.23 W. You may still have a problem if your switching frequency is high, more power will be dissipated during the switching.

Comment: You need to specify the stored energy by L and DCR of the transformer to  get or simulate actual Pd.  You can’t expect Vmax and I max unless you have a max heat sink and are running DC only.

Comment: Primary side of a transformer means what? flyback? full bridge? Either way, a good 20% margin is advisable over the max expected voltage when the snubber is active. For non inductive loads, 40V at 3A is just fine for the IRFZ44/IRLZ44

Comment: Since you don't sound too experienced let me warn you that you need to put a flyback diode across the transformer primary. Otherwise the very first time you try to turn off your MOSFET it will probably fail short.

Comment: Also, 70 Hz square wave means high for 7.14 ms, then low for 7.14ms then repeat. Are you sure you can turn on the MOSFET for 7.14ms without the current exceeding 3A? How is the current being limited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't handle 50 volts at 50 amps, that would fry it immediately. It can handle either 50 volts *or* 50 amps. 50 volts when turned off (Vgs < Vth) and 50 amps (in pulses *only*, or with extremely good heatsinking!) when turned fully on (Vgs >> Vth).

If you're using it at 40 V, it should be perfectly fine. 40 V at 3 A is quite a bit of power, however, and you'll probably need liquid cooling for that much heat--that's 120 watts, more than your average CPU! Most likely, what you mean is 40 V when the FET is *off* (which is well within its rated 50 volts) and 3 A when it's *on*, which is (very!) well within its rated 50 A. If turned on hard enough, which for this FET is at a Vgs as low as just 4 volts, the power dissipation will be \$R_{ds,on}·I_D^2 = 315\ \mathrm{mW}\$, using the \$R_{ds,on}\$ at Vgs = 4 V found in [this](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567217c32725) datasheet. This is low enough that you could probably get away with not using a heatsink at all, especially if it's pulsed.

Comment: So if I use two in parallel, do you think it will be more than enough to keep things cool without a heatsink

Comment: I don't think you need to use two in parallel, but you can if you want. 315 mW will result in a temperature rise, with no heatsink, of about 20 °C above ambient, which is well within the rated temperature and not even hot enough to burn you unless it's already a really hot day. And if you're driving the FET with 5 V, that power dissipation drops to a level where you're only going to see it heat up by about 14 °C.

Answer (score 4):

> *I already have the datasheet, it states it can handle 50 Volts at 50
> Amps*

The data sheet says it can handle 55 volts and the data sheet also says it can handle 47 amps but, it never says that it can handle both this situations at the same time for any length of time. So, when you say *50 Volts at 50 Amps* you are misinterpreting things as well as getting the actual numbers wrong a little.

So, if you really wanted to know what it can handle you'd look at this graph: -

[image]

And figure out what voltage and current that can be simultaneously handled over what period of time and then degrade your expectations a little bit to account for anomalies and spikes.

Comment: I should have thought of talking about the SOA graph in my answer!

Comment: The you would estimate the L/(DCR+Ron)=T to estimate the pulse width. Max and the XL(f) to estimate the excitation current or Amp-s I the case of flyback

Answer (score 1):

The IRFLZ44N is a 22 mOhm FET.  With 3A the power dissipation will be 0.2W causing about 12 degrees C temperature rise.  So the current isn't a problem if the FET is fully on.

However you don't push voltage through a FET.  The FET can stand off 40V when it's off, but personally I would use a higher voltage rating for more margin.

If you really want 40V and 3A with the FET in linear mode you'd better look for a different part or a really good thermal management system.  (Heatsink, forced air cooling, liquid cooling, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a margin of 20% at least when dealing with Vdsmax of power Mosfet's.

Pick a more robust Mosfet if you can.

The leakage inductance of the transformer will produce voltage spikes on the drain of your Mosfet that might go well beyond 50 V.

I assume here that you are designing a flyback power supply.

Comment: Using a 50 V rated part at 40 V is already a margin of 20%; I wouldn't be concerned about it especially because the datasheet I found actually has its rating at 55 volts.